# Rendering problems following a tutorial

Tags: android

As sugested by someone else to look at tutorials to learn something on how to code something in android, I took a look at [this tutorial](http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90). I created a new project in `AndroidStudio` and replaced the `activity_main.xml` as shown with the following code (and did not change anything else):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This leads to the preview to vanish, but with a rendering problem:

```
 Rendering Problems Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?  Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.  Failed to find style 'listViewStyle' in current theme (6 similar errors not shown) "?attr/listPreferredItemHeight" in attribute "minHeight" is not a valid format. (Edit) (3 similar errors not shown)
```

How to fix this? Or is there a tutorial, a full working example of how to use a `ListView` available somewhere?

[image]

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alexander.testapplication" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

gradle.build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.alexander.testapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your manifest file ?

Comment: I added the Manifest

Comment: Post your module's Gradle file too

Comment: Which one? I see one for Project:TestApplication and one for Module: app

Comment: Rebuild your project and it should work fine from Build ->Rebuild Project

Comment: the Module : app one

Comment: @Alex everything looks just fine, you must refresh it all : clean & rebuild your project, refresh your preview editor...

Comment: That seems to work...!!